# binary search counter not updating

Tags: c, binary-search

I have two arrays, a fixed Array A and a dynamically updating array X. I am trying to find the max interleaving factor i for X^i, such that X^i is a subsequence of A.

My X and A arrays are populating correctly, as I've tested them on each iteration through the binary search.  However, my counter is not.

Here is my code:

```
void binary_search(int size_a, int * A, int size_x, int *X, int max_i, int min_i){

    int j, k, max_repeat = 0;

    while(min_i <= max_i){

        int i = 0, count = 0, repeats = (max_i + min_i)/2;

        printf("\n");
        int * temp = malloc(size_x * sizeof(int) * repeats);

        for(k = 0; k < size_x; ++k){
            for(j = 0; j < repeats; ++j){
                temp[k * repeats + j] = X[k];
            }
        }

        printf("New X: ");
            for(i = 0; i < size_x * repeats; i++){
                printf("%d ", temp[i]);
            }

        printf("A: ");
        for (i = 0; i < size_a; i++){
            printf("%d ", A[i]);
        }

        for(j = 0; j < size_a; j++){
            if(A[j] == temp[i]){
                count++;
                i++;
            }
        }

        printf("Count: %d", count);


        if (count >= size_x * repeats){
            printf("Low: %d Mid %d High % d Passes\n", min_i, repeats, max_i);
            min_i = repeats + 1;
            max_repeat++;
        }
        else{
            printf("Low: %d Mid %d High % d Fails\n", min_i, repeats, max_i);
            max_i = repeats - 1;
        }

        free(temp);
    }   
        printf("Max repeat: %d", max_repeat);
}
```

Array A = [4,3,2,1,4,3,2,1,4,3,2,1,4,3,2,1,4,3,2,1] and X = [1,2,3] initially. So X^3 = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]. This should fail, because count is not > = size_x * repeats (count should be 5 on this iteration), and it does, but count = 0 throughout each iteration when it should clearly update. What am I missing? I have been staring at this for way to long, so I'm sure it's something simple.

**EDIT** Expected value:

```
Low 0 Mid 3 High 6 Fails

Low 0 Mid 1 High 2 Passes

Low 2 Mid 2 High 2 Fails
```

Actual value:

```
Low 0 Mid 3 High 6 Fails

Low 0 Mid 1 High 2 Fails

Low 0 Mid 0 High 0 Passes
```

Comment: if count shouldn't be equal 0 throughout each iteration, try to put it outside the while loop.

Comment: But I need count to reset to zero before each iteration.